# Why do horizontal curves have zero covariant derivative along their projection?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**Background:** Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.  Let $(p,v) \in TM$ and $V, W \in T_{(p,v)}TM$.  We can introduce a Riemannian metric on $TM$ via $$\langle V, W\rangle_{(p,v)} = \langle d\pi(V), d\pi(W) \rangle_p + \left\langle \frac{D\alpha}{dt}\!(0), \frac{D\beta}{dt}\!(0)\right\rangle_p,$$ where $\alpha, \beta\colon I \to TM$ are curves in $TM$ with $\alpha(0) = \beta(0) = (p,v)$ and $\alpha'(0) = V$ and $\beta'(0) = W$, and $\pi\colon TM \to M$ is the natural projection.

Given this metric on $TM$, we then call $\text{Ker}(d\pi) \subset T_{(p,v)}TM$ the *vertical space*, and its orthogonal complement the *horizontal space*.  We say that a curve $\alpha\colon I \to TM$ is *horizontal* iff its tangent vector $\alpha'(t) \in T_{\alpha(t)}TM$ is horizontal for all $t \in I$.

> **Question:** How can one show that a curve $\alpha\colon I \to TM$ is horizontal if and only if $\alpha$ is parallel along its projection curve $\pi\circ \alpha$?

**Source/Motivation:** This is Problem 2(b) from Chapter 3 of do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry."  It was assigned as a homework problem, and the homework was collected the other day (Oct 27), but I was unable to do the forward direction $(\implies)$ of the problem.

I would especially appreciate a coordinate-free proof if possible.

---

**My Attempt:**

Suppose $\alpha'(t)$ is horizontal, so $\langle \alpha'(t), W \rangle_{\alpha(t)} = 0$ for any vertical vector $W \in T_{\alpha(t)}M$.  Since $d\pi(W) = 0$, we have that $0 = \langle \alpha'(t), W \rangle_{\alpha(t)} = \langle \frac{D\alpha}{dt}\!(0), \frac{D\beta}{dt}\!(0)\rangle_{(\pi\circ\alpha)(t)}$, where $\beta\colon I \to TM$ is a curve with $\beta(0) = \alpha(0)$ and $\beta'(0) = W$.

It seems to me that if we chose $W$ cleverly enough, then we could perhaps conclude that $\frac{D\alpha}{dt}\!(0) = 0$, which is what we want to show.

**Other thoughts:**

- Perhaps an application of Gauss' Lemma could help somewhere?
- While attempting to prove this problem, I conjectured that if $\alpha'(t) \in T_{\alpha(t)}TM$ is horizontal, then $d\pi(\alpha'(t)) = \alpha(t)$.  However, even if this is true -- it certainly seems likely -- I am not sure how to apply it to get a solution.

Comment: A note on your second "other thoughts": that $\alpha$ is a parallel vector field along the curve $\pi\circ\alpha$ is independent of parametrisation. On the other hand, $\alpha'$ **is** dependent on parametrisation. So the expression $d\pi(\alpha'(t)) = \alpha(t)$ cannot hold for arbitrary parallel vector fields (and hence for arbitrary horizontal $\alpha'$). In particular, if you let $\alpha(t) = \alpha(0)$ the constant curve, you have $\alpha' = 0$ and $d\pi(\alpha'(t)) \neq \alpha(t)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there.

Observe the following: if $W$ is vertical, $d\pi(W) = 0$. Using the (assumed) knowledge that the metric on the tangent bundle $TTM$ *is* a Riemannian metric and hence non-degenerate, we have that for any non-vanishing vertical $W$, the corresponding map
$$ \langle \cdot, \frac{D\beta_W}{dt}(0) \rangle_p \in T^*_pM $$
is non-zero (since its action on $D_t\beta_W(0)$ is non-zero).

Now applying the rank nullity theorem to the map $d\pi$ (we are working with finite dimensional Riemannian manifolds, right?) you have that the vertical space of $T_{p,v}TM$ has the same dimension as $T_pM$. So applying the rank nullity theorem again to the linear map 
$$ W\mapsto \langle \cdot, \frac{D\beta_W}{dt}(0)\rangle_p $$
you see that it is invertible.

So what you have shown, that for **any** vertical $W$, $\langle D_t\alpha(0), D_t\beta_W(0)\rangle = 0$ implies that $D_t\alpha(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Warning: There follows my answer, I do not know if I have been enough clear, but anyway you can find the original argument on page 343 in Sasaki's paper [The differential geometry of the tangent bundles of Riemannian manifolds](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/tohoku-mathematical-journal/volume-10/issue-3/On-the-differential-geometry-of-tangent-bundles-of-Riemannian-manifolds/10.2748/tmj/1178244668.full).  However any feedback is highly appreciated.

Notations: Let $x$ be a coordinate system on $M$, and let us denote by $(x,y)$ and $((x,y),(u,v))$  the associated standard coordinate systems respectively on $TM$ and $T(TM)$ .

The part(a) of do Carmo's problem requires to prove that the displayed scalar product on the fibers of $\tau_{T(TM)}:T(TM)\to TM$ is well-defined.
In order to show this, you have to prove, for any $(x,y)\in TM$, and $(u,v)\in T_{(x,y)}(TM)$, that $\frac{D\alpha}{dt}\!(0)\in T_xM$ is independent by $\alpha$, for $\alpha$ varying among the curves on $TM$ such that $\alpha(0)=(x,y)$, and $\alpha'(0)=(u,v)$.
Infact, preserving the previous notations, you should have proved that $$\frac{D\alpha}{dt}\!(0)=(x,v+\Gamma[x](y,u)).$$
(Where $\Gamma$ is the bilinear map whose components are the Christoffel symbols.)
This holds because the expression for the covariant derivative along an arbitrary curve $t\in I\to\alpha(t)=(x(t),y(t))\in TM$ is $\frac{D\alpha}{dt}\!(t)=(x(t),y'(t)+\Gamma[x(t)](x'(t),y(t))$, as reported in formula (1) on page 51 in do Carmo.

The same identical argument implies that:

> a curve $\alpha(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ is autoparallel, i.e. $\frac{D\alpha}{dt}(t)\equiv 0$, iff $y'(t)+\Gamma[x(t)](y(t),x'(t))\equiv 0\ (\ast)$.

If the metric on $M$ is $g_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j$ then the metric on $TM$ is $$g_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j+g_{ij}\left(dy^i+\Gamma^i_{kl}y^k dx^l\right)\otimes\left(dy^j+\Gamma^j_{mn}y^m dx^n\right).$$

Now we find that:

> an element $(u,v)$ in $T_{(x,y)}M$ is horizontal iff $v+\Gamma[x](y,u)=0\ (\ast\ast)$.

This follows from the coordinate expression of the Sasaki metric and because an element $(u,v)$ of $T_{(x,y)}M$ is vertical iff $u=0$.

From $(\ast)$ and $(\ast\ast)$, we conclude that:

> a curve $\alpha(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ is autoparallel, iff $\alpha'(t)=(x'(t),y'(t))$ is horizontal for all $t$.